# question on a multi valued function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta, r \sin\theta)$, where $(r,\theta) \in \mathbb R^2, r\neq 0$. Then how to disprove the following?

1. for any $(r,\theta) $ such that $r\neq 0$,  $f$ is one-one on a neighbourhood of $(r,\theta) $.
2. $Df(r,\theta) = r^2I$ for any $(r,\theta) $ such that $r\neq 0$.

My attempt:- I found out that $Df(r,\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
                                               \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\
                                               \sin\theta & r\cos\theta
                                              \end{pmatrix}$.
So by substituting any value of $(r,\theta)$ the matrix is not equal to $r^2I$. But I do not know how to disprove the first statement. Please help me.

Comment: Also please tell me how the function is one to one on $\{(r,\theta)| r \neq 0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, with $r\in\mathbb R^+$.
$f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R)$ and the Jacobian matrix of the function is
$$J_f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&&-r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&&r\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}.$$
The determinant is given by $\det(J)=r\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta=r> 0\implies\exists U(p_0)$ and $V(f(p_0))$ open neighbourhoods $\forall p_0=(r,\theta)\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\times\mathbb R$ such that $f|_U:U\to V$ is invertible.
Since the restriction is locally bijective, the function will be one-one in every neighborhood of a point in its domain.